# Center only one element inside of a div with tailwind

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm struggling with `TailwindCSS` and I'm a bit lost. I'm trying to create a `nav` with some elements inside, but I want one of the elements to be centered in the middle of the nav, ignoring the other elements inside. I tried this:

```html
<nav class='py-3 z-50 bg-white border-gray-200 shadow px-2  flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between'>
  <div id='1' class='flex flex-row border-red-400 border-2'>
    <p>Here goes content more larger</p>
    <p> than ocuppies a bit mmore</p>
  </div>

  <div id='2' class="flex justify-center items-center basis-100 place-content-center border-red-400 border-2">
    <p>Content that I want in the center on the nav</p>
  </div>

  <div id='3' class="border-red-400 border-2">
    <p>Other content</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <p>This is the center</p>
</div>
```

With `justify-between` the space is almost what I want (elements 1 and 2 at `start` and `end`), but it puts the same space between elements, and de `div` with id 2 is not centered regarding the `nav`

Is it possible to maintain the `divs` 1 and 2 at the end of the `nav` but centering the `div` with id 2 ignoring the other elements?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I tried another approach that would be the key, but I don't know if it's the right path. I change `flex` by `grid`, doing this

```html
<div>
  <nav class='py-3 z-50 bg-white border-gray-200 shadow px-2  flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between'>
    <div id='1' class='flex flex-row border-red-400 border-2'>
      <p>Here goes content more larger</p>
      <p> than ocuppies a bit mmore</p>
    </div>

    <div id='2' class="place-content-center border-red-400 border-2">
      <p>Content that I want in the center on the nav</p>
    </div>

    <div id='3' class="border-red-400 border-2">
      <p>Other content</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div #content class="flex items-center justify-center mb-24">
    <p>This is the center</p>
  </div>

  <nav class='py-3 z-50 bg-white border-gray-200 shadow px-2 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-5 items-center'>
    <div id='1' class='flex flex-row border-red-400 border-2'>
      <p>Here goes content more larger</p>
      <p> than ocuppies a bit mmore</p>
    </div>

    <div id='2' class="place-self-center hidden md:flex border-red-400 border-2">
      <p>Content that I want in the center on the nav</p>
    </div>

    <div id='3' class="place-self-end border-red-400 border-2">
      <p>Other content</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: You will probably need fixed width for your elements. With dynamic content, I'm afraid it's very hard to achieve the layout you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you simply want the central component somewhat left as shown in the image below.

so I had added a `left margin` according to the screen size

```
<nav class='py-3 z-50 bg-white border-gray-200 shadow px-2  flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between'>
  <div id='1' class='flex flex-row border-red-400 border-2'>
    <p>Here goes content more larger</p>
    <p> than ocuppies a bit mmore</p>
  </div>

  <div id='2' class="flex justify-center items-center basis-100 place-content-center border-red-400 border-2 md:-ml-32 lg:-ml-72">
    <p>Content that I want in the center on the nav</p>
  </div>

  <div id='3' class="border-red-400 border-2">
    <p>Other content</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <p>This is the center</p>
</div>
```

Please find the code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Yzlz4LyunX?layout=horizontal&size=1344x720)